# If I dont use this code the instagram image is never displayed

Tags: php, image, echo, readfile, cross-origin-resource-policy

The picture is displayed in my website only when I use this code ...

```
<?php
$remoteImage = "https://scontent-frt3-2.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-19/s150x150/67310557_649773548849427_4130659181743046656_n.jpg?tp=1&_nc_ht=scontent-frt3-2.cdninstagram.com&_nc_ohc=M1hegfYF3_AAX9GkTGH&edm=AAuNW_gBAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=50ba784cd64600a025031f7fc00740c1&oe=60BAEE93&_nc_sid=498da5";
$imginfo = getimagesize($remoteImage);
header("Content-type: {$imginfo['mime']}");
readfile($remoteImage);
?>
```

but if use this:

```
<?php 
$link = "https://scontent-frt3-2.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-19/s150x150/67310557_649773548849427_4130659181743046656_n.jpg?tp=1&_nc_ht=scontent-frt3-2.cdninstagram.com&_nc_ohc=M1hegfYF3_AAX9GkTGH&edm=AAuNW_gBAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=50ba784cd64600a025031f7fc00740c1&oe=60BAEE93&_nc_sid=498da5";
echo "<img src='$link'>"; 
?>
```

It shows corrupted image like here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrXRp.png and it happens only with instagram images because the ending of the url is not like xxxx.jpg
Please help !

Comment: Look at the network tab in the browser's developer tools. What does the response for that particular image say? Instagram probably doesn't like its images to be hotlinked.

Comment: thanks for the answer, can I save the image and call it back to get arround of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had used your browser's console to actually debug the whole thing, you'd have gotten your answer.

Regarding your variants:

1. Is downloading the actually image to your server and outputs the binary content.
2. Is embedding the image by using the `img` tag, therefore the client will request the image from Instagram's CDN directly.

The reason why variant 2) isn't working, is a rather simple one:

[image: Same Origin]

I will just quote Chrome's devtools here:

> To use this resource from a different origin, the server may relax the
> cross-origin resource policy response header:
> `Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy: same-site`
> Choose this option if the
> resource and the document are served from the same site.
> `Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy: cross-origin`
> Only choose this option if
> an arbitrary website including this resource does not impose a
> security risk.

And the policy of Instagram's CDN is set to `cross-origin-resource-policy: same-origin` - which denies requests from other origins. More about this can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cross-Origin_Resource_Policy_(CORP)).

Examples about what an Origin is (i.e. scheme + host + port) can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Origin).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, is there any way to get around of this?

Comment: Probably by using their [API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram/oembed/)

Comment: Alright thank you, I have a question: why I can do it using the first code?

Comment: and is there a way to use that code to get arround and play with the image?

Comment: The first code is downloading the image to your server, you can probably do it like that for a small amount of images. But you could probably just do `$image = file_get_contents($url)` - however, I guess your server's IP address may get blocked by Instagram in a short period of time.